# InvalidCastException out of ISynchronizeInvoke

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use a dll file which has a few events in it. When trying to use the code below I get:

> "An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'"

and

> "Unable to cast object of type 'qweqwe_po.MyHandler' to type
>   'System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke'."

I have no clue why this is happening and need some help. If I use the code within MyHandler in either Form1 or Form2 it works so I'm guessing something is wrong with my delegate. Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

The fault is triggered on the row (MyHandler):

```
((ISynchronizeInvoke)d.Target).BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { this, e });
```

Form1

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MyHandler obj;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            obj = new MyHandler();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Form2 f = new Form2(obj, new Random().Next(20,80)+1))
            {
                f.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
```

Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private MyHandler obj;

    public Form2(MyHandler p_obj, double sum)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        obj = p_obj;
        textBox1.Text = sum.ToString();

    }
}
```

MyHandler

```
public class MyHandler
{
    private figure fig;
    public event FigureEventHandler FigureEvent;
    private double m_Sum;

    public MyHandler()
    {
        init();
    }

    public void init()
    {
        fig = new figure();

        // PIM event
        fig.OnStatus += new IFigureEvents_OnStatusEventHandler(fig_OnStatus);
        fig.OnReturn += new IFigureEvents_OnReturnEventHandler(fig_OnReturn);
        FigureEvent += new FigureEventHandler(MainWindow_FigureEvent);


        int res = 0;
        if ((res = fig.open("192.168.16.68") != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("figure.dll open failed. Error: " + res);
            return;
        }

        if ((res = fig.startConnection()) != 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Error starting com test");
    }

    public void fig_OnStatus(short statusType)
    {
        OnFigureEvent(new FigureEventArgs(integrationEvents.STATUS, statusType));
    }

    public void fig_OnReturn()
    {
        OnFigureEvent(new FigureEventArgs(integrationEvents.RESULT, 0));
    }

    protected virtual void OnFigureEvent(FigureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FigureEvent != null)
        {
            foreach (Delegate d in FigureEvent.GetInvocationList())
                ((ISynchronizeInvoke)d.Target).BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { this, e });
        }
    }

    public void MainWindow_FigureEvent(object sender, FigureEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.IntegrationEvent)
        {
            case integrationEvents.STATUS:
                // status logic
            case integrationEvents.RESULT:
                //result logic
        }
    }

    public bool Send(transTypes p_TransType, double p_Value)
    {
        int res = 0;
        if (p_TransType == transTypes.TRANS_NONE || fig.Busy != 0)
            return false;

        res = fig.Send(0x30);
        if (res != 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Error calling Send(): " + res);
        return !Convert.ToBoolean(res);
    }
}

public class FigureEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private readonly integrationEvents integrationEvent = integrationEvents.NONE;
    private readonly short statusType = 0;

    public FigureEventArgs(integrationEvents integrationEvent, short statusType)
    {
        this.integrationEvent = integrationEvent;
        this.statusType = statusType;
    }

    public integrationEvents IntegrationEvent { get { return integrationEvent; } }
    public short StatusType { get { return statusType; } }
}

public delegate void FigureEventHandler(object sender, FigureEventArgs e);
   }
```

Comment: The *why* is pretty clear: you are trying to cast a `MyHandler` object (`d.Target`) into a `ISynchronizeInvoke` but `MyHandler` doesn't implement that interface.

Comment: Because `Control` does implement it, so `Form` does too.

Comment: I didn't implement the interface when it was working in Form1 and Form2. Why do I need to implement it here? Not trying to sound like a jerk, just wondering

Comment: Ok. What logic should be in the new methods? Don't understand why I need them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're breaking stuff. The original code marhsalled the event callback on the UI thread of the associated control (the old `MainWindow_FigureEvent`).

```
foreach (Delegate d in FigureEvent.GetInvocationList())
 ((ISynchronizeInvoke)d.Target).BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { this, e });
```

This basically says "take all the delegates added in the invocation chain of the event, and invoke them on the thread of the instance of the class that they are defined in".

So if you cause the event to fire from a different thread than the UI thread of the original control, the delegate execution will be marshalled to the UI thread, rather than proceeding on the thread that caused the event to fire.

**Multi-threading is hard**

You have to be extremely careful. The guy who wrote the original code had a reason for doing so. Understand the reasons. Make sure whether they make sense or not. If not, you can just use `FigureEvent()` instead of that for-each. However, if they still do make sense, the whole thing you're attempting here can never work - you've thrown away the information about which thread you need to marshall back to by adding the callback to the `MyHandler` class instead of the `Form`.

Changing things like this *will* bring tons of side-effects. It doesn't sound like you're quite capable of dealing with the complexities involved, so if possible, try to work with someone more experienced with multi-threading. If that's not possible, try to stay as close as possible to the original implementation. It sounds like you're trying to get rid of some repeating code. It's hard to give you any direct pointers on how to properly handle this, though, because that's the parts of code you're not showing. But the main idea would be not to handle this through a `MyHandler` class like this, but rather shoving the common parts of the implementation to a separate class, while keeping the event handlers on their `Form`s. You'll probably need to rewrite a few bits here and there, add some interfaces, maybe inheritance.

Going back to the code excerpt we do have, note the following things that changed when you moved the event handler to `MyHandler`:

- `d.Target` is no longer the form. This causes your `InvalidCastException`.
- `this` is no longer the form. Ouch again. Are you sure the event handler doesn't expect the `sender` argument to be the form?

In fact, you've thrown away the information about the form completely. The architecture you're working with isn't exactly obvious, so I can't really show you how to fix everything, but at least you should be on your way :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Luaan. Appreciate it.